# Python simple moving average class based

Tags: python, class, methods, average, self

Ok so I'm writing a class that will calculate a simple moving average on a list of prices. It calculates the average every N number of prices with out calculating the first N-1 days. This is what I have:

```
class Simplemovingaverage():
    def __init__(self, Nday, list_of_prices):
        self._Nday = Nday
        self._list_of_prices = list_of_prices

    def calculate(self):
        for i in range(len(self._list_of_prices)):
            if i < self._Nday:
                average = 0
            elif i == self._Nday:
                average = sum(self._list_of_prices[:self._Nday])/self._Nday
            else:
                average = sum(self._list_of_prices[i-self._Nday:i])/self._Nday
            print(average)
```

I tested it by making a class object on the shell `'x = Simplemovingaverage(3, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])'` and then doing the calculate method by 'x.calculate' the output I got was:

```
0
0
0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
7.0
8.0
```

So from my list of numbers its only calculating up to 7,8,9 the last number should be 9 because that's the average of 8,9,10 and also there should only be 3 zeros since N is 3. This is the output I'm looking for:

```
0
0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
7.0
8.0
9.0
```

Comment: Why make a class for this? There doesn't seem to be any object with state or behavior you're modeling; it's just doing a computation. This would work better as a function.

Comment: Take a look at using a [deque](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) object for moving averages. It is optimized for appends and pops on either end, as well as fixed sizes (if needed)

Comment: Simply use the [moving_average recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-recipes) from `collections.deque`.

Comment: I agree with the question about why you are using a class, but even more fundamentally: why are you printing the result, instead of creating a new list and returning it?

Comment: output should be `0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`, not `0, 0, 0, ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's a cleanup:

```
class Simplemovingaverage():
    def __init__(self, navg, items):
        self.navg = navg
        self.items = items

    def calculate(self):
        av = []
        for i in range(len(self.items)):
            if i+1 < self.navg:
                av.append(0)
            else:
                av.append(sum(self.items[i+1-self.navg:i+1])/self.navg)
        return av
```

First, you need to use `i+1` everywhere, since `range` gives `0...navg-1` rather than `1...navg` (you could also do `range(1, n+1)`).

Second, you don't need to special-case `i+1==self.navg` (`:m` is the same as `0:m`).

Third, it makes more sense to return a list rather than printing the results (although I like the other respondent's idea of using `yield` to make this a generator!)

Fourth, there's no real reason to hide the number and the list, so I've removed the underscores (python isn't java or c++!).

Finally, this is more general than a "list of prices" averaged over a certain number of "days", so I've renamed the parameters for more generality.

Comment: Why would I need the +1 in "if i +1 < self.navg:"?

Comment: Have you tried it? That (or `i<self.navg-1`) is what you need to get the right number (`navg-1`) of 0s at the start: when `i=0, 1, ... navg-2`

Comment: For this list of numbers I only need 2 zeros, maybe you didn't see I changed it; I put 3 zeroes at first but that was a mistake. It works fine with just "if i < self.navg:".

Comment: No, it doesn't! You want `n-1` zeros, and `range` starts counting at 0. That's one of the reason your code *doesn't* work!

Comment: exactly I need n-1 zeros, with n as 3 I get two zeros. The zero is just to say that you can calculate a simple moving average on n-days without the first n-1. When I change the zero to '' an empty space it gives me 2 empty spaces and then the averages starting at 3 which is what I need. When I put the +1 it gives me 1 empty space and a zero before it starts calculates the average of 3. I think you misunderstood the role of the zeros.

Comment: Victor, have you run my code (with `i+1` *everywhere*)? It does what you request! If `navg=3`, it gives 0 for `i=0,1` (since `1<navg-1` is `1<2`) and the average thereafter. The crucial point is that `i` *starts at 0, not 1!*

Comment: Ok I apologize your code does do what I request, but mine also does. The thing is that I didn't use all of your code until now, I had it like in the other answer "if i < self.navg-1" which does the same thing. When I looked at your code I changed everything except for that on mine that's why I was getting something else. Does it really matter if I add 1 to i or subtract 1 from navg?

Comment: No, of course not. (But of course I prefer all the other changes I suggested, too!)

Answer (score 3):

```
def sma_calc(prices_list, window_size):
    return sum(prices_list[-window_size:]) / window_size
```

Comment: Your answer could use a little more explanation.

Comment: Fair enough, thx. I don't mean to detract from the subject, the goal was to handle SMA using a class. Just thought that there might be some like myself that prefer to keep things simple, I use those lines in algorithmic trading code. Just send it a list of numbers (floats in my case) and a lookback window size (integer) and it'll return the current simple moving average value.  Right now I use 3 sma's so I find that handy/convenient/flexible. What we don't see is that prices_list is being appended with a price for each trading bar before being sent to that function. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import division
from itertools import islice, tee

def moving_average(n, iterable):
    # leading 0s
    for i in range(1, n):
        yield 0.

    # actual averages
    head, tail = tee(iterable)
    sum_ = float(sum(islice(head, n)))
    while True:
        yield sum_ / n
        sum_ += next(head) - next(tail)
```

When run as

```
list(moving_average(3, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
```

returns

```
[0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

(starts with N-1 leading 0s, meaning the output list has the same cardinality as the input list, which I think is what you actually wanted).

Comment: You actually don't need it to be class based, there is no need for it.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an out by one error.  Try this:

```
  for i in range(len(self._list_of_prices) + 1):
```

So this might illustrate what's going on a bit

```
>>> _list_of_prices = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> len(_list_of_prices)
10
>>> range(len(_list_of_prices))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> i = 9
>>> _list_of_prices[i-3:i]
[7, 8, 9]
```

So the problem is that the python's list slice operator returns up to i in the example above but not i, (in this example it returns 
i-3, i-2 and i-1) e.g.

```
>>> word = "helpa"
>>> word[0:2]
'he'
```

See here http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: Sorry got distracted then fixed it in place

Comment: Also you don't need the elif i == self._Nday: special case?

Also _Nday is not in line with the python style guide.. _n_days is more pythonic (if that kind of thing matters to you).

Comment: You're doing something slightly weird here.. I can't quite put my finger on

Comment: yeah.. your out by one is in your understanding of the list slice operator.

Answer (score 0):

You've mistaken the index:

```
In [186]: class Simplemovingaverage():
     ...:     def __init__(self, Nday, list_of_prices):
     ...:         self._Nday = Nday
     ...:         self._list_of_prices = list_of_prices
     ...: 
     ...:     def calculate(self):
     ...:         for i in range(len(self._list_of_prices)):
     ...:             if i < self._Nday-1:
              #------------------------^^--------------------------
     ...:                 average = 0
     ...:             elif i == self._Nday-1:
              #---------------------------^^--------------------------
     ...:                 average = sum(self._list_of_prices[:self._Nday])/self._Nday
     ...:             else:
     ...:                 average = sum(self._list_of_prices[\
                                i+1-self._Nday:i+1])/self._Nday
              #-----------------^^^-------------^^^--------------------------                  

     ...:             print(average)

In [187]: x = Simplemovingaverage(3, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

In [188]: x.calculate()
0
0
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```